# Skobbler SDK on Android: SKMapSurfaceListener.onAnnotationSelected does not get called

Tags: android, skmaps

I have an `SKMapSurfaceView` that I've set a listener on (via `setMapSurfaceListener`, passing in an `SKMapSurfaceListener` object). When I tap on an annotation that was added to the `SKMapSurfaceView` via `addAnnotation`, the listener gets an `onSingleTap` event, but not `onAnnotationSelected`. I see in Skobbler's logs that it detects a tap on a "custom POI", which I assume is my annotation (esp. since the ID of that custom POI in their log is the unique ID that I've given to my annotation). But neither `onAnnotationSelected`, nor `onCustomPOISelected` gets called in my listener. Why?

Edit: here's my code:

```
        SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
        annotation.setUniqueID(123456);
        annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(
                13.45457,
                52.51592));
        annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(15);
        annotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_MARKER);
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);

        mapView.setMapSurfaceListener(new SKMapSurfaceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSingleTap(SKScreenPoint arg0) {
                Log.d("onSingleTap");
            }

            @Override
            public void onScreenOrientationChanged() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRotateMap() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPOIClusterSelected(SKPOICluster arg0) {
                Log.d("onPOIClusterSelected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapRegionChanged(SKCoordinate arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapPOISelected(SKMapPOI arg0) {
                Log.d("onMapPOISelected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapActionUp(SKScreenPoint arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapActionDown(SKScreenPoint arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(SKScreenPoint arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onInternetConnectionNeeded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onInternationalisationCalled(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleTap(SKScreenPoint arg0) {
                Log.d("onDoubleTap");
                float zoom = mapView.getZoomLevel() + 1;
                if (zoom <= SKMapSurfaceView.MINIMUM_ZOOM_LEVEL) {
                    mapView.setZoomSmooth(zoom, 250);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCustomPOISelected(SKMapCustomPOI arg0) {
                Log.d("onCustomPOISelected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompassSelected() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnnotationSelected(SKAnnotation annotation) {
                Log.d("onAnnotationSelected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationsFinished() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActionZoom() {
                Log.d("onActionZoom");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActionPan() {
                Log.d("onActionPan");
            }
        });
```

And then the logs I get if I do one tap somewhere NOT on the annotation, and then one tap ON the annotation:

```
06-22 19:34:27.674: D/SKMaps(20852): MapRenderer----onSurfaceCreated
06-22 19:34:27.679: D/SKMaps(20852): MapRenderer---- LinInitialized = true 
06-22 19:34:28.394: D/SKMaps(20852): MapRenderer----Map follower mode 0
06-22 19:34:28.394: D/SKMaps(20852): MapRenderer----onSurfaceChanged width = 1080 height= 1701
...
06-22 19:35:11.729: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----SINGLE TAP  CONFIRMED 0
06-22 19:35:11.729: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----Check north indicator   4 526.0 705.0 296 64 0 64
06-22 19:35:11.729: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----notifyWithMapInfo
06-22 19:35:11.759: D/Wanderant(20852): onSingleTap
06-22 19:35:17.399: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----SINGLE TAP  CONFIRMED 0
06-22 19:35:17.399: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----Check north indicator   4 532.0 720.0 296 64 0 64
06-22 19:35:17.399: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView----notifyWithMapInfo
06-22 19:35:17.429: D/SKMaps(20852): SKMapSurfaceView---- Tapped custom POI id=123456
06-22 19:35:17.429: D/Wanderant(20852): onSingleTap
```

As you can see, in both cases I get the onSingleTap callback.
(I've skipped the Skobbler maps initialization code, but it's done according to the tutorial and it does initialize successfully and shows the map, etc.)

Comment: Hi Todor. I'll need more info to be able to debug this issue. Can you include the code for one of the annotations you are trying to tap and the log you get in the console (indicating where the tap was detected)?

Comment: Edited my original post to include the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing was a bug present on the 19'th of May SDK.

We tested this behaviour in the next SDK update (ETA 30 June, 2014) and now `onAnnotationSelected` is correctly called every time. So please update your SDK once the new version will be available (you should receive a email/newsletter when the update is available)

Comment: Hi, I updated the SDK with the latest version downloaded today (version 2.1.0) and the issue still exists, with the exact same messages in the log, with the only exception that after "SINGLE TAP  CONFIRMED", it now says "null" instead of "0". But my onAnnotationSelected is not being called. I still get a call to onSingleTap only. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm... please contact dev@skobbler.com as more investigation & code is required.

Comment: It turns out that I wasn't clearing old annotations and THOSE were the ones that weren't working. With the new SDK (2.1.0), clicking on annotations works, as long as they are the currently-added annotations and they're not left over from a previous screen. I'm now using deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs() to clear all old ones before displaying my map screen. Thanks for your help.